# How to specify dependencies when creating the setup.py file for a python package

Tags: python, package, setup.py

The python doc for "Writing the Setupscript (http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) mentions that dependencies can be specified under section

> **>  2.4. Relationships between Distributions and Packages**
>
> [...] These relationships can be specified using keyword arguments to
>   the distutils.core.setup() function.
>
> Dependencies on other Python modules and packages can be specified by
>   supplying the requires keyword argument to setup(). The value must be
>   a list of strings. Each string specifies a package that is required,
>   and optionally what versions are sufficient.
>
> To specify that any version of a module or package is required, the
>   string should consist entirely of the module or package name. Examples
>   include 'mymodule' and 'xml.parsers.expat'.
>
> [...]

Given this rather sparse information without an example I just want to make sure that I do it right. Also, I cannot find this `requires` parameter in the API description http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/apiref.html#distutils.core.setup

So is it done like this,e.g.,

```
setup(name='MyStuff',
      version='1.0',
      requires='os, sys, progressbar',
      [...]
```

I hope some one can give me a little bit more insight! Thanks!

EDIT:

To address the distutils.core, setuptools controversy, one could simply do

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup
```

Does it make sense?

Comment: The whole Python packaging system is badly documented, mainly because there are so many different places with partly very good, but contradictory information. I always look at existing projects. In case you do not have special needs, you only need distutils. For example bottleneck has is a good example for a `setup.py` file that only used distutils: https://github.com/kwgoodman/bottleneck/blob/master/setup.py

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke: Yet `bottleneck` fails to specify that it requires `numpy` in the metadata. `setuptools` has much better documentation these days, thanks to the `distribute` fork being merged back: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/

Comment: Right you are, it even starts with importing numpy right away.

Comment: that's a very nice example, I will save it to my references!

Comment: I think a good solution would be to have something like `try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup` (I will add it to my question, the formatting is just ugly here in the comments)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Ignore `distutils`. If you want to create a package that specifies dependencies for a tool like `pip` to go out and find for you, you need to base your `setup.py` of off [`setuptools`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) instead.

`setuptools` dependencies are listed in [`install_requires`](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#declaring-dependencies), which takes a list:

```
setup(name='MyStuff',
      version='1.0',
      install_requires=['progressbar'],
      # ...
)
```

which should be distributions of their own. `os` and `sys` are modules included with Python and *should not be listed*.

Comment: I recently had a longer discussion about this and got convinced that in the current situation a good idiom is `try: from setuptools import setup; except ImportError: from distutils.core import setup`.

Comment: @Jan-PhilipGehrcke Just a FYI that `setup` from `distutils.core` does not support `install_requires`. So if you attempt to use it, you will see a message like this: */usr/lib/python3.4/distutils/dist.py:260: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'install_requires'*. So in light of this and other differences, I don't think that's a very good idiom under anything but the most straightforward circumstances.