# Compiling and distributing Cython extensions

Tags: python, numpy, cython, packaging, setuptools

I have a python package (python 2.7) that includes some optimized functions written in cython. My setup.py handles the pure-python files and the installed package uses the un-optimized pure python functions.

I'm trying to understand what is the best way to setup the project for distributing the C extension.

Right now  I have a specific `setup.py` in the extension folder that can be used to compile the extension with:

```
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

But I want the package installation to also handle the C extension. Possibly with a single:

```
python setup.py
```

I was thinking of merging the specific setup.py in the project-wide setup.py. However, to compile the extension, I need to import numpy. But I know that importing anything outside the standard lib in setup.py is discouraged.

What are the best practices for python packages including a simple cython extensions that only uses numpy and no other external libs?

Comment: `But I know that importing anything outside the standard lib in setup.py is discouraged.` Where did you find that?

Comment: It will break installing the package as a dependence in a new virtualenv. See for example: https://github.com/lmfit/lmfit-py/issues/149

Comment: I would recommend seeing how other projects solve this: e.g. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/blob/master/setup.py
I would not state that importing third party modules is discouraged. However it's true that you cannot just write `import numpy` without getting into trouble. A mix of defensive importing with the `try` statement and using setuptools `install_requires` probably solves the problem for you.

Comment: Do you know the difference between `requires` and `install_requires`?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727398/how-to-specify-dependencies-when-creating-the-setup-py-file-for-a-python-package

Answer (score 2):

For now I settled on the following solution that requires importing numpy. It does not cause problems so far.

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.extension import Extension
import numpy as np
import versioneer

## Metadata
project_name = 'foobar'
long_description = """
Long description in RST. Used by PyPI.
"""

## Configure versioneer
versioneer.VCS = 'git'
versioneer.versionfile_source = project_name + '/_version.py'
versioneer.versionfile_build = project_name + '/_version.py'
versioneer.tag_prefix = '' # tags are like 1.2.0
versioneer.parentdir_prefix = project_name + '-'

## Configuration to build Cython extensions
try:
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext
except ImportError:
    # cython is not installed, use the .c file
    has_cython = False
    ext_extention = '.c'
else:
    # cython is installed, use .pyx file
    has_cython = True
    ext_extention = '.pyx'
ext_modules = [Extension("corecalculation_c",
                         [project_name + \
                         "/calculation/corecalculation_c" + ext_extention])]

## Configure setup.py commands
cmdclass = versioneer.get_cmdclass()
if has_cython:
    cmdclass.update(build_ext=build_ext)


setup(name = project_name,
      version = versioneer.get_version(),
      cmdclass = cmdclass,
      include_dirs = [np.get_include()],
      ext_modules = ext_modules,
      author = 'Author Name',
      author_email = 'email@address',
      url          = 'http://github.com/USER/PROJECT/',
      download_url = 'http://github.com/USER/PROJECT/',
      install_requires = ['numpy', 'scipy', 'matplotlib', 'ipython'],
      license = 'GPLv2',
      description = ("Oneline description"),
      long_description = long_description,
      platforms = ('Windows', 'Linux', 'Mac OS X'),
      classifiers=['Intended Audience :: Science/Research',
                   'Operating System :: OS Independent',
                   'Programming Language :: Python',
                   'Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7',
                   'Topic :: Scientific/Engineering',
                   ],
      packages = [project_name, project_name+'.utils'],
      keywords = 'keyword1 keyword2',
      )
```