# How to package python modules that are not in the standard Library

Tags: python, pymysql

I have a script that I would like distributed on other machines, however it has a dependent module that is not a part of the python standard library. More specifically I want to use the pymysql library. When I am on my local machine I can just use pip install pymysql, but want to know if there are other options in packaging/distributing my script so that others do not have to run pip install pymysql.

My current error on other machines is:
ImportError: No module named pymysql

Answer (score 1):

You can define dependencies inside your `setup.py` file. Try doing something like this:

```py
setup(..., install_requires=['pymysql'])
```

If you are using `setuptools` to package your library. Here is some documentation: https://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/dependencies.html

This question may help you some more: [How to specify dependencies when creating the setup.py file for a python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17727398/how-to-specify-dependencies-when-creating-the-setup-py-file-for-a-python-package)

By doing this, if anyone installs your library, it will automatically install all the dependencies too.

If you need to define dependencies for a GitHub repository, you can define a `requirements.txt` file and keep it with the main code inside the repository (not inside any folder). This is how yours might look:

```
pymysql
```

It's just 1 line containing the requirements. If you have any more, simply type them on the next line:

```
pymysql
numpy
pandas
```

If anyone clones your repository, they will need to execute the following command in the directory in which they have cloned the files:

```
python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: To give a little more context consider the following application:
/myApplication
--- myScript.py
--- setup.py
in myScript.py I import pymysql.

I am trying to push this to a git repo and have others clone this and run myScript.py. Would they just need to run python setup.py in order to have all of the dependencies downloaded?

Comment: This setup file would work well if you are uploading this as a PyPi package. You can also define dependencies for a GitHub repo using a `requirements.txt` file. I'll add this to my answer.